# How can I fix this IF statement error in sql

Tags: sql, mariadb

I got into a problem with the SQL IF statement. And I tried a few another statement, but it doesn't work too.

I got my code here:

```
DELIMITER $
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    IF user = 'test' THEN 
       SELECT fox FROM conv WHERE user = test;
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO pending_conv (pending) VALUES ('test');
    END IF;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

And the error message:
`#1327 - Undeclared variable: user`

I know I'm bad at this because I'm new to this. I appreciate all your anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are attempting to do, but you could pass in a value when calling a stored procedure. Do this by adding an IN parameter to the CREATE PROCEDURE statement and give the parameter a name and data type:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(IN in_user VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    IF in_user = 'test' THEN 
       SELECT fox FROM conv WHERE user = 'test';
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO pending_conv (pending) VALUES ('test');
    END IF;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Call the stored procedure and pass a value for user like this:

```
CALL my_procedure('some_user');
```

Comment: You should not use parameter names that are the same as the column names. MariaDB cannot know which one to use. Use prefix for parameters instead (for example `in_user`).

Comment: Yes. Good point. I missed this.